# Wordpress AJAX request 400 bad request

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

I am trying to get some html code over ajax request.But i am getting ajax 400 bad request always.There are some other requests also but those are not doing any problem.

Below is my code

```
jQuery(document).on('click', '.evecal-month-view-control', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var month = jQuery(this).data('month');
    var year = jQuery(this).data('year');
    _getMonthCalendar(month, year);
});

var _getMonthCalendar = function(month, year){
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: eventcaldata.ajaxurl,
        data:{
            action: 'ec_ajax_get_months_table',
            month: month,
            year: year,
            nonce: eventcaldata.nonce,
        },
        beforeSend: function(){

        },
        success: function(response){
            console.log(response);
        }
    });
}
```

Don't know what is the problem.everything seems okay

Here is the nonce code

```
public static function adminassets(){
    wp_enqueue_style( 'eventcal-admin-css', WP_EVECAL_CSS_URL . 'style-admin.css', array(), '1.0', 'all' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'pe7stroke.css', WP_EVECAL_FONTS_URL . 'pe-icon-7-stroke.css', array(), '1.0', 'all' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'eventcal-admin-js', WP_EVECAL_JS_URL . 'script-admin.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.0', true );
    $localize = array(
        'ajaxurl'   => admin_url('admin-ajax.php'),
        'imagesurl' => WP_EVECAL_IMAGES_URL,
        'nonce'     => wp_create_nonce(WP_EVECAL_SLUG),
    );
    wp_localize_script( 'eventcal-admin-js', 'eventcaladmindata', $localize );
}
```

Comment: Where is your nonce created?

Comment: @designtocode question updated with nonce code

Comment: Do you have wp_ajax hooks being called anywhere?